# How can I fix this warning from Google Chrome? Cookie... `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`

Tags: angular, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-authentication

This piece of code 
**this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider())**
are generating this warning on Chrome:

*A cookie associated with a resource at http://google.com/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.*

Comment: found an anwser at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191969/how-to-fix-set-samesite-cookie-to-none-warning-chrome-extension but it think it's due to an old Google Analytics setup.

Comment: [This entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270663/samesite-warning-chrome-77) might be of some help

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread but faced this issue now. Seems we can't set cookies **SameSite=none** without Secure flag now.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).