# A cookie associated with a cross-site resource was set without the `SameSite` attribute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, cross-site, samesite

Chrome is giving me the following warning:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://quilljs.com/
>   was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome
>   will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set
>   with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

*Note that quilljs.com is a 3rd party domain.*

I have seen [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270663/samesite-warning-chrome-77) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191969/how-to-fix-set-samesite-cookie-to-none-warning-chrome-extension), the answers on both questions are similar, some say something like this:

> nothing to do with your code. its something their web servers will
>   have to support.

While others provide an answer like this:

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict");
```

I am not sure if this is something that I need to fix in my website, or is it something that should be fixed on the 3rd party library?

Comment: I get the same error for other libraries as well, such as: *A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://cloudflare.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The warning messages specifically call out the domain that's responsible for the cookie. In this case, it's `quilljs.com`. If that's your domain, then you need to update the cookie there. If it's a third-party service that you rely on, then it's that service that needs to update their cookies.

**Edit**
More context is available at https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained and https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, are you able to include a reference for this please?

Comment: Updated with some context!

Comment: Hi, I have been to those two references but I still don't quite understand it. Unlike the author, I write my own php at ipage.com. Do I need to set a cookie on the php file or on the html file? I have never set any cookies before.