# Why am i getting this?

Tags: aframe

I am getting this warning on my website with aframe

`` A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://aframe.io/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032. ``

Comment: It needs elaboration. Best is to share a link to a simple A-Frame page that reproduces the issue. Glitch is usually a good option: https://glitch.com/~aframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830297/a-cookie-associated-with-a-cross-site-resource-was-set-without-the-samesite-at) its the issue with aframe.io

[A cookie associated with a cross-site resource was set without the `SameSite` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830297/a-cookie-associated-with-a-cross-site-resource-was-set-without-the-samesite-at)

as @rowan_m stated

The warning messages specifically call out the domain that's responsible for the cookie. In this case, it's `aframe.io`. Which means 'aframe.io' needs to update the cookie there.

https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained

https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes.