# PHP setting a Session-Cookie with SameSite for php 7.4

Tags: php, cookies, csrf, php-7.4

Recently upgraded my PHP version to 7.4 but getting **403 Access Forbidden by CSRFProtector!**, I have tried below code with an associative array with samesite key but it not worked

```
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => $cookie_timeout,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => $cookie_domain,
    'secure' => $session_secure,
    'httponly' => $cookie_httponly,
    'samesite' => 'Lax'
]);
```

The solution which is given inside below link is worked for PHP7.3 what would be the solution for PHP7.4

[PHP setting a Session-Cookie with samesite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58317981/php-setting-a-session-cookie-with-samesite)