# zend Framework 1 how to set Samesite=none; secure

Tags: web, zend-framework, session-cookies

I'm trying to add the "Samesite=None; Secure" to a cookie on website running the Zend Framework 1.
I found the doc for the framework however I dont see how I can set the parameter - does anyone know how to do it?
https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.9/en/zend.http.cookies.html

[image: Chrome Dev console]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not supported.

You can use the php setcookie method though, you don't need to use Zend class for that. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128675/112000)