# How Can I check if Third-Party cookie disabled - My project stopped by this problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, setcookie

How can I check if Third-Party enabled or disabled

I'm use on my project NodeJS + Express JS + HTML / JS in front

so I need a solution can I use it with Express or just from front JS

because I tried to use `navigator.cookieEnabled` and it's alway `true`

I have the error exactly on **Chrome mode Incognito** + **Safari v3**

**How my project works**

my project work inside an iframe of my website (it's really important to work inside it)

and in the iframe, I have something like login to detect if is logged or not and I save the details + I save other data in the cookies (Third-Party)

so I just want to know how can I detect if the customer block Third-Party from the browser

or just how can I detect Chrome Incognito

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923761/how-to-detect-third-party-cookies-had-being-blocked-without-a-page-refresh

Comment: Hi, doesn't work for me