# Which of the following determines whether cookies are enabled in a browser or not?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, navigator

Which of the following determines whether cookies are enabled in a browser or not?

Option 1

```
(navigator.Cookie)? true: false
```

Option 2

```
(application.cookieEnabled)? true: false,
```

Option 3

```
(navigator.CookieEnabled)? true: false,
```

Option 4

```
(application.cookie)? true: false
```

Comment: None, `navigator.cookieEnabled` is the right one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if third-party cookies are enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550790/check-if-third-party-cookies-are-enabled)

Comment: NONE of those actually exists - so ... why would you even ask?

Comment: Dear Jaromanda X, I have to ask to clear confusion. Please donot write any further comments in my questions.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `navigator.cookieEnabled`:

```js
console.log(navigator.cookieEnabled);
```