# How to detect if Prevent Cross-site tracking is active on Safari 13 with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I would like to detect when Prevent Cross-site tracking is active in a browser using JavaScript.

My challenge is trying to find a method to detect this and show a warning popup to the user when this cross-site tracking is disabled by a users browser. This became essential after Safari 13 disabled it as default. I believe this might be helpful for people who are using cookies on iframes.

There are some ways such as

[Check if third-party cookies are enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550790/check-if-third-party-cookies-are-enabled)

and

https://gist.github.com/iansltx/18caf551baaa60b79206

which are trying to bypass this security feature with using different methods and some of them are not valid anymore.

Basically what I try to achieve is from an iframe, try to detect Prevent Cross-site tracking is enabled on the browser using JavaScript.

I tried using this code:

```
var receiveMessage = function (evt) {
  if (evt.data === 'MM:3PCunsupported') {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'not supported';
  } else if (evt.data === 'MM:3PCsupported') {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'supported';
  }
};
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

However, this solution doesn't seem to work any more.

Comment: did u find a solution to it ever?

Answer (score 1):

For Safari browser specifically, you can use a combination of feature detection and error handling to determine if cross-site tracking prevention is active. Although there isn't a direct, foolproof method to detect this setting due to privacy and security considerations, you can use a workaround to infer its status based on the behavior of third-party cookies. Here's a simplified approach to achieve this:

Checking Third-Party Cookie Support
Attempt to Set a Third-Party Cookie:

```
document.cookie = "test_cookie=test_value; SameSite=None; Secure";
```

Check if the Cookie Was Set:

```
var cookieSet = document.cookie.indexOf("test_cookie=test_value") > -1;
if (cookieSet) {
  // Third-party cookies are supported
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Third-party cookies are supported';
} else {
  // Third-party cookies are blocked (cross-site tracking prevention may be active)
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Third-party cookies are blocked';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Google Analytics on your site and adding code to detect if it loads. If it doesn't load, then its likely that tracker blockers are active.

Example:

```html
<script>
var active;
</script>
<script src="https://googletagmanager.com/…" onerror="active = 1;"></script>
<script>
if (active !== 1) {
alert('Prevent cross site tracking is disabled');
} else {
alert("Ok")
}
</script>
```