# 3rd party cookie detection using parent url only

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Is it possible to detect whether 3rd party cookie is enabled or disabled in a browser setting simple from visiting a site?

Lets say I have a hosted gitpage and I want to detect whether my 3rd party cookie is enabled or disabled via an alert or a console (limitation is that the html page does not have any other hosted url of a different domain within it). Would it still be able to detect just by using the parent domain url?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to detect 3rd party cookie support, without actually trying to set a 3rd party cookie and read it again, so if you only control a single domain in the scenario you are working in, you are out of luck.

Comment: so any workaround as to how can we set a 3rd party cookie and try to read it? within that single HTML file? any JS code for that please

Comment: There's a whole lot of solutions for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550790/check-if-third-party-cookies-are-enabled