# Check if Third-Party Cookies are Disabled

Tags: cookies, magento2

I'm working on a Magento2 project. I need to know if the client browser has third-party cookies disabled.
I already saw this post [Check if third-party cookies are enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550790/check-if-third-party-cookies-are-enabled) but it doesn't work anymore on chrome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774792/1397021

Answer (score 1):

Put this code on your Third Party App/Site

```
var CookieName = "TestCookie";
document.cookie = "CookieName=TestCookie;samesite=None; secure";

if (document.cookie.indexOf(CookieName) == -1) {
  console.log("Cookies are required to use shopping carts.");
if (document.cookie.indexOf(CookieName) != -1) {
  console.log("Thank you for enabling Third-Party cookies");
}
```