# Detect if Safari blocks or allows cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, safari, local-storage

There are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled), and [Check if third-party cookies are enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550790/check-if-third-party-cookies-are-enabled), but none work with Safari 15.2.

Under Safari preferences, if you enable the "Block all cookies" option, `window.localStorage' generates an error.

This code fails to detect the situation.

```
function areCookiesEnabled() {
    try {
      document.cookie = 'cookietest=1';
      var cookiesEnabled = document.cookie.indexOf('cookietest=') !== -1;
      document.cookie = 'cookietest=1; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT';
      return cookiesEnabled;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Catching errors to `window.localStorage` is one approach, but is there a more robust, more recommended way to detect this situation in Safari 15.2? As indicated by other users, this approach fails in Chrome.